# Уведомления из шторки, Android

Tags: android

Как я могу получить в своем приложении все уведомления, содержащиеся в шторке? **AccessibilityService** немного не устраивает, т.к. получается получить только новое уведомление. То, которое висело в шторке до запуска сервиса вытащить не получается. Или, я делаю что-то не так. **NotificationListenerService** тоже не устраивает из-за минимальной версии API 18.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте сервис, который будет постоянно мониторить уведомления.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?